# How to solve for $u(x, y)$ satisfying $u_x + u_y = 1$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I apologise, since this question does already exist. But I cannot for the life of me understand how it is solved. Could anyone provide me with a simplified version of the solution?

Comment: That is exactly the question that I saw that exists. Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: What do you know about solving partial differential equations?

Comment: What is the first part you don't understand?

Comment: I am trying to understand the method of characteristics, and I understand that the solution remains a constant on the same curve. My tutor suggested solving the equations using such a curve but I don't really seem to understand him that well.

Comment: What do you mean by a simplified version of the solution? The equation $u_x+u_y=1$ is specific example of the general equation $au_x+bu_y=c$. The theory for these equations is one of the topics covered at the beginning of a partial differential equations course. What are you confused about in regards to the method of characteristics? I could write a different solution to your problem but it might not help you if you haven't done at least one example on your own.

Comment: In my textbook, the method for solving $au_x + bu_y = 0$ is covered. However, the method for the inhomogeneous equation wasn't very well explained to me. I was hoping to get a more detailed explanation.
For example, in this solution, https://stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%202/StraussPDEch1s2p09.pdf
why does $y(\xi, 0)$ have parameters?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the method of characteristics: the charactistics here are the lines $x+y=$constant.  It's **not** true that the solutions are constant on such a curve.
Rather, the PDE tells you how the solution changes on each characteristic curve.
In this case, the characteristic curves are $y = x + c$ for arbitrary constant $c$.  If we write $u(x, x+c) = g(x)$, the PDE (together with the chain rule) says
$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} g(x) = u_x(x,x+c) + u_y(x,x+c) = 1 $$
You can integrate that to get $$g(x) = x + \text{constant}$$
where the constant can depend on $c$, i.e.
$$ u(x,x+c) = x + K(c)$$
where $K$ is arbitrary.  Writing $x+c=y$, this says
$$ u(x,y) = x + K(y-x)$$
$K$ is an arbitrary function, but should be differentiable for the pde to be defined.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me. However, I would like to clarify your statement that "It's not true that the solutions are constant on such a curve." If the equation were homogeneous, i.e. for $u_x + u_y = 0$, would the solution $u(x, y)$ then be a constant on the characteristic curve?

Comment: Yes, the solutions of $u_x + u_y = 0$ are constant on the characteristic curves.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.